# Layouting the parent of a parent of a parent

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, swt

We have a tool, that has a GUI which contains multiple [Sections](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/Section.html). In these sections, we have [Expandable Composites](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/ExpandableComposite.html) which are not expanded by default. When we try to expand these composites, the *+* becomes a *-*, but it stays closed:
[image: Expandable Composite stays closed]

To fix this, I tried to add an ExpansionListener:

```
ExpandableComposite extendedConfiguration = getToolkit().createExpandableComposite(parent, TREE_NODE);
extendedConfiguration.setLayoutData(new GridData(FILL, CENTER, true, false, 2, 1));
extendedConfiguration.setText("Erweiterte Einstellungen");
extendedConfiguration.setExpanded(false);
extendedConfiguration.addExpansionListener(new ExpansionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) {
        parent.getParent().getParent().layout();
    }
});
```

Using this dirty bit of code, it works, `parent` is the Composite of the parent. The parent of the parent is the Section itself, the parent of the Section is our view. It not only looks stupid, but also is problematic when we want to change our view, as the parent of the parent ... may won't be the right parent.

What is the correct way to layout our view again? How can I force the UI to draw the contents of our ExpandableComposite?

Comment: Have you tried to use `pack();` instead of `layout();` ? If you use org.eclipse.forms.ui.Form you can also try `form.reflow(true);` instead of `layout();`

Comment: @jens-na: I'm not using a form, it's just a composite. Also, pack() doesn't help here.

Comment: The content which should be expanded should be the client of the expandable composite. E.g.: `extendedConfiguration.setClient(contentComposite);`. Do you have something like this in your code?

Comment: @jens-na Yes, the composite is set as client. The parent of the composite is also the `extendedConfiguration`, as documented for `setClient`.

Answer (score 0):

I think just firing resize event should do the trick for you

```
 parent.getParent().layout(true);
 parent.getParent().notifyListeners(SWT.Resize, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

First: try to invalidate your composite component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a layout of the top level window:

```
extendedConfiguration.getShell().layout();
```

Source: [SWT counterpart of revalidate method of SWING's JComponent](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t24201.html)

Comment: It does not do anything :(.